# Edit List View Order

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, form

I'd like the "edit" view to be in the same order as the column view on the "list".

Currently when clicking "edit" it shows the columns in order of creation rather than the order they show on the "list" view.

Does anyone know how I can change this?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**:

You can change the order of column in list view by selecting the column header and then moving it to left/right.

Check below documentation for more information: [Change the column order in a list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-column-order-in-a-list-or-library-6f14f5a4-1df4-48a8-a57b-dc1b8f8d03d2)

**Note**: After changing the order, **Save view as** from view selection dropdown (save with same name).

---

**Solution 2**:

1. Go to SharePoint list.
2. Click on view selection dropdown --> Select **Edit current view**.

[image]

3. Select the necessary columns & Change the order using **Position from Left** dropdown.
4. Click **OK**

[image]

---

**Additional Reference**

Follow steps given in below article, if you want to change the order of columns on **list form** as well as on **list view**.

[How to change the order of columns in a SharePoint list or library](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-change-the-order-of-columns-in-a-sharepoint-list-or-library/)

Comment: Apologies I don't think I was clear. I have the list view setup correctly, however, when going to edit the data that forms the list view, the order is not in the list view order, rather, the created order.

Comment: In that case check the link titled: "How to change the order of columns in a SharePoint list or library" under "Additional Reference" section in my answer. You need to change the column order on list forms for that.